# Dependency injection integration with Unity.MVC, container.Resolve cannot be used with arguments of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to integrate Dependency Injection with Unity.MVC to my project. With the default configuration that Unity has, controllers works perfectly fine but I would like to implement DI en other classes...

This is the configuration I use:

- I added this line on global.asax UnityMvcActivator.Start();

```cs
public static class UnityMvcActivator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Integrates Unity when the application starts.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(UnityConfig.Container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            // Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            UnityConfig.Container.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The last one comes by default and works perfectly with the controllers

```cs
public static class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container =
          new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
          {
              var container = new UnityContainer();
              RegisterTypes(container);
              return container;
          });

        /// <summary>
        /// Configured Unity Container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer Container => container.Value;
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or
        /// API controllers (unless you want to change the defaults), as Unity
        /// allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously
        /// registered.
        /// </remarks>
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below.
            // Make sure to add a Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            // container.LoadConfiguration();

            // TODO: Register your type's mappings here.
            // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
            if (Global.BOT_CONECTADO)
            {
                container.RegisterSingleton<ISeguidorRepository, DBSeguidorRepository>();
                container.RegisterSingleton<IActivoRepository, DBActivoRepository>();
                container.RegisterSingleton<ICategoriaRepository, DBCategoriaRepository>();
                container.RegisterSingleton<IJuegoSecundarioRepository, DBJuegoSecundarioRepository>();
                container.RegisterSingleton<ISaludosRepository, DBSaludosRepository>();
            }
            else
            {
                container.RegisterSingleton<ISeguidorRepository, FakeSeguidorRepository>();
                container.RegisterSingleton<IActivoRepository, FakeActivoRepository>();
                container.RegisterSingleton<ICategoriaRepository, FakeCategoriaRepository>();
                container.RegisterSingleton<IJuegoSecundarioRepository, FakeJuegoSecundarioRepository>();
                container.RegisterSingleton<ISaludosRepository, FakeSaludosRepository>();
            }

            //DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new IDConfigurador(container));
        }
    }
```

In the last one I added my registers, but When I try to use them on other contructors, those that are not controllers, they don't work. Looking for answers on google I found this solution that could help me:

container.Resolve()

I tried to use it but I get the following error ==> "The method 'IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type, string, params ResolverOverride[])' non generic cannot be used with arguments of type"

```cs
// CONSTRUCTOR
public RepositorioEncuesta()
            {
                // Error línea de abajo: El método 'IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type, string, params ResolverOverride[])' no
                // genérico no se puede usar con argumentos de tipo
                _activos = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<IActivoRepository>(); 
                _seguidores = new DBSeguidorRepository();
                _juegos = new DBJuegoSecundarioRepository();
            }
```

How could I use my DI integration to use it on other constructors? Why the Resolve method is not working?

PD: I also tried using a generic, but does not work either.

`var activos = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<IActivoRepository>();`

Comment: Please define "not working". Are you getting a C# compile error, or a *runtime* error. In case of the runtime error, please post the full details of the stack trace. In case of a compile error, please post the relevant code and the full C# compiler error message.

Comment: You might be missing a namespace declaration in your C# file. If I'm not mistaken, there are overloads to `Resolve` defined as extension methods. You'll have to look in which namespace those extension methods are located.

Comment: Holly Molly! I cannot believe that the only problem I had, was an 'using' missing. Normally, Visual itself tell you What imports you need, but this wasn't the case. Thanks!